# Random variable X's density function is $x+\frac{1}{2}\delta (x)$, $x\in [0,1]$. $Y=(X-\frac{1}{2})^{2}$. What are the mean, and variance of Y?

Tags: probability

This is what I did (I skipped steps to save word count and for clarity's sake):

$$F_{Y}(y)=P(Y\leqslant y)=P((X-\frac{1}{2}))^{2}\leqslant y)=...=F_{X}(\sqrt{y}+\frac{1}{2})-F_{X}(-\sqrt{y}+\frac{1}{2})$$ (CDF)

Then, its pdf is

$$f_{Y}(y)=(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}})f_{X}(\sqrt{y}+\frac{1}{2})+(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}})f_{X}(-\sqrt{y}+\frac{1}{2})$$ with $y\geq 0$

Using the basic definition for mean: $E[Y]=\int yf_{Y}(y)dy$, I get

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{y}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2}\delta (\sqrt{y}+\frac{1}{2})+\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2}\delta (-\sqrt{y}+\frac{1}{2})dy$$

And I asked the question on how to integrate $\int \frac{\sqrt{y}}{2}\delta (\sqrt{y}+\frac{1}{2})dy$ (which I can also apply to $\int \frac{\sqrt{y}}{2}\delta (-\sqrt{y}+\frac{1}{2})dy$) in another post, but no one seemed not be possible to integrate it.

Then, I need $E[Y^{2}]=\int y^{2}f_{Y}(y)dy$ to find variance and standard deviation. I get

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{y^{3}}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{y^{3}}}{2}\delta (\sqrt{y^{3}}+\frac{1}{2})+\frac{\sqrt{y^{3}}}{2}\delta (-\sqrt{y}+\frac{1}{2})dy$$

And I think it is even more difficult to integrate $\int \frac{\sqrt{y^{3}}}{2}\delta (\sqrt{y}+\frac{1}{2})dy$ and $\int \frac{\sqrt{y^{3}}}{2}\delta (-\sqrt{y}+\frac{1}{2})dy$

One educated guess is that I must have missed something or made some mistakes in above steps (This was taken from a test question. Usually professors won't give students test questions that himself/herself cannot solve.)

Please tell me what I have done wrong. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is $\delta(x)$?

Comment: It is impulse function.

Comment: Please reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response